MongoDB Slow Query issue
I am facing slow query issue in  my mongoDB database, the indexing is done properly, I have checked that there is no duplicate numeric id, even though I am getting a slow query issue. The query I am using is findOne in which it is scanning the entire data base and returning one document only. It is also reporting that in this operation it cannot able to  use the index  and the operation execution time is around 40-50 ms which is resulting is slow query issue. What could be done to avoid this scenario.
The collection looks like this
{_id: "MongoDBId";
userId: "MongoDBId";
arrFlield1: "arrayOfString";
arrField2 : "arrayOfString";
numericId : "Integer"}

And the query I am using is
db.collection.findOne({userId:"userId"})


You may want to include the MongoDB version, the code used to create the index, and tell how many documents are there in the collection. Do a db.collection.getIndexes() and verify that the index on userId exists. To know if an index is used for a query use the explain() to generate a query execution plan.

Thanks @prasad_ after I attached the index to the userId this isuue was solved.
I used this :-    db.collection.creatIndex({userId:1})

After I attached the index to the particular querying field userId this issue was solved. The thing happened was that indexing was attached _id, it needs to be attached to querying field which was not done. As mentioned by @_prasad, I first get the Index using this command.
db.collection.getIndexes()

Then I created index on the particular query field by using the below command.
db.collection.createIndex({userId:1})

